# Close google sheet opened in a new tab by assigning a script to a button

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a code that allows for a copy of a sheet to be opened in a new window on clicking a button. The purpose is so that the users do not tamper with the master sheet but be able to fill the copy and exit the sheet by clicking on the button "submit" that I drew at the bottom of the sheet. How do I embed a code/function that will close the copy of the sheet when the user clicks on the "submit" button?. I will appreciate any help/pointers with this

```
 function copytheSheet(){
  
var SSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById(Form_sheet_id);
 var user = Session.getEffectiveUser().getUsername(); 
 var dest = DriveApp.getFolderById('XXXXX'); 
 var name =  SSS.getName()+ user + " Copy ";
 var newfile = DriveApp.getFileById(Book.getId()).makeCopy(name,dest);
 var link = newfile.getUrl();

return link; 

}


function modalUrl(){
    var url1 = copytheSheet();
    var name = 'Click here';
     //gives the option of clicking the link and opening in a new tab
    var html = '<html><body><a href="'+url1+'" target="blank" onclick="google.script.host.close()">'+name+'</a></body></html>';
    
    //Automatically opens in a new tab
    var html1 = '<html><script>'
      +'window.close = function(){window.setTimeout(function(){google.script.host.close()},9)};'
      +'var a = document.createElement("a"); a.href="'+url1+'"; a.target="_blank";'
      +'if(document.createEvent){'
      +'  var event=document.createEvent("MouseEvents");'
      +'  if(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("firefox")>-1){window.document.body.append(a)}'                          
      +'  event.initEvent("click",true,true); a.dispatchEvent(event);'
      +'}else{ a.click() }'
      +'close();'
      +'</script>'
      // Offer URL as clickable link in case above code fails.
      +'<body style="word-break:break-word;font-family:sans-serif;">Failed to open automatically. <a href="'+url1+'" target="_blank" onclick="window.close()">Click here to proceed</a>.</body>'
      +'<script>google.script.host.setHeight(40);google.script.host.setWidth(410)</script>'
      +'</html>';
    
    var will = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html1);
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(will.setHeight(100),"Opening the form. Please wait...");
    
    }
```

Comment: I wouldn't expect that you could get a script to be able to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Just as it is not possible to open a spreadsheet on the browser using Google Apps Script, it is also not possible to close a sheet either. The reason for this is Google Apps Script has no access to modify your browser tabs.

Note that while the `HtmlService` would allow you to display HTML windows client-side, they are opened **within** the Google Sheet tab, not as a **new tab** on the browser.

**Reference:**

[Class HtmlService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-service)

[Class HtmlOutput](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-output)